# ssh X forwarding: GUI window opens on remote

Tags: ssh, kde, manjaro, xforwarding, dolphin

I am running dolphin (KDE's file manager) over SSH as follows:

```
[abhishek@brixpro ~]$ ssh -Y optiplex
[abhishek@optiplex ~]$ dolphin .
```

The dolphin window opens on the local machine (brixpro). However, in the dolphin window, when I click a PNG file or a text file, they get opened in windows on optiplex (remote) not brixpro.
How do I get the windows to open on the local machine (brixpro)?

Both the machines (optiplex and brixpro) are running Manjaro linux.

Comment: It should "just work". Do you have anything like `export DISPLAY=:0` in your `~/.bashrc` on `optiplex`? If I was debugging this I would get the PNG fle opened via dolphin, log into optiplex, then run "ps -ef" to find the PID of the PNG viewer (say for example it is 5601). I would then use `tr '\0' '\n' < /proc/5601/environ | grep DISPLAY` to see what it value it has. It should NOT be :0

Comment: Indeed, I see DISPLAY=:0 for the png viewer (gwenview). But I see localhost:12.0 for dolphin. My ~/.bashrc does not appear to change DISPLAY. If I type gwenview directly on the commandline after ssh -Y, instead of clicking an image in dolphin, gwenview opens on brixpro.

Comment: So `something` is setting the DISPLAY environment variable, which is the cause of your issue. The problem is to figure out what the `something` is. My usual tool for figuring this out is `strace`, but it can be intimidating so lets try something simpler. We want to see if $DISPLAY is either unset, `:0` or somthing followed by a colon followed by something greater than 0, and probably greater than 10. After you use 'ssh -Y', then `echo $DISPLAY` is localhost:12.0. If in that shell you type `bash` to run a subshell, does `echo $DISPLAY` show the same thing or has it changed to `:0`?

Comment: after typing bash, there is no change to the $DISPLAY variable

Comment: Hmm, so that ruled out something changing an interactive but not login shell. Next test case `bash -c env | grep DISPLAY`, to check a non-interactive shell.

Comment: returns `DISPLAY=localhost:12.0`

Comment: So not anything set for a non-interactive shell. OK, let us see how dolphin calls gwenview. So get dolphin to launch gwenview, find the PID of dolphin (say 6723), then run `pstree -p 6723` and see if there are any intermediate programs between dolphin and gwenview,

Comment: I dont see `gwenview` in the children of the dolphin process. I checked the parent of  `gwenview`. It was `plasmashell`

Comment: OK, I have no idea what plasmashell is. The basic idea is to use the `tr '\0' '\n' < /proc/XXXX/environ | grep DISPLAY` to see where the value changes from something like `localhost:12` to `:0`. So you can start with gwenview, look at the parent (plasmashell), look at the grandparent and so on.

Comment: plasmashell seems to be the main process for the KDE Plasma desktop environment running on the remote. So, as expected, it's DISPLAY is :0

Comment: OK. So this suggests that this is a misconfiguration (or design mistake) of dolphin, that it is sending a request to plasmashell to get it to display the image rather than   invoking a program to display it. At this point I don't think I can help any more (sorry), I don't use either dolphin or KDE.

Comment: Thanks. I learnt many things from your comments. As a result, I better understand the problem.